# What word that describes a person who only cares about race

Tags: word-choice, verbs, nouns, adjectives

I'm looking for a word that describes SJW, feminist people or others who  judge entertainment, political or social topics by race and diversity. Note: I was thinking about the word racist but that implies hatred towards a race

Comment: Prejudice? http://www.dictionary.com/browse/prejudice

Comment: Sounds like https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ethnicism

Comment: Do you mean, for example, someone who says "I don't like musical group X because they are all white, I only like groups with some diversity" (without listening to group X's music)?

Comment: What is *SJW*? Are you looking for a word for people  who ***like*** SJW or people who ***are like*** SJW (whatever that is)?

Comment: @1006a SJW is an acronym for Social Justice Warrior. Wikipedia has a page on the term here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_justice_warrior

Comment: Thanks, @GetzelR. That should really be spelled out in the question—folks shouldn't need to Google acronyms in order to understand a question.

Comment: @1006a Agreed. This particular question isn't mine - I did some very minor editing to fix grammatical errors, but expanding that acronym in a fair way would have been more than I had time for. At any rate, I think the second half of the sentence explains it enough that you can understand the question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I fear that the question is a request for a derogatory word to apply to one side dispute between progressive and traditional social views.  It involves a social hostilty fuelled by vocabulary of this kind.  If I am wrong I apologise.

Answer (score 5):

The suffix "-centric" is defined in Oxford Dictionary of English as

> forming an opinion or evaluation originating from a specified
>   viewpoint

An example for this is Eurocentric, defined as

> focusing on European culture or history to the exclusion of a wider
>   view of the world; implicitly regarding European culture as
>   preeminent.

Replace "Europe" with "race" and perhaps "**race-centric**" would best describe someone whose viewpoint originates or revolves around race. This is an adjective, not a noun like "racist," (at least for the moment) but you might find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

I initially dismissed this, remembering it only as a British synonym for racist, but I looked it up and it fits the bill:

> [*Racialism*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/racialist)
>   a. An emphasis on race or racial considerations, as in determining policy or interpreting events.
>   b. Policy or practice based on racial considerations.

The word you are looking for is **racialist**.